# Installing Ubuntu in C drive of windows, delete files from other drives?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, delete, windows-vista

I have 5 partitions of which c: is the windows partition which has nothing but windows installed. Other drives contain important files. So will installing ubuntu on C: drive and replacing windows, delete files from other drives ?

Comment: It should not, just be careful not to format any other partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So will installing ubuntu on C: drive and replacing windows, delete
>   files from other drives ?

Of course not. You have to be careful in which drive you will install Ubuntu , because Ubuntu(Linux) not recognize the drives as Windows . I mean C: , D: , E: .. etc.

At the installer window (of Ubuntu) you will see dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 .. etc and you have to choose the correct partition that corresponds to C:

Comment: Thank you so much! I am confirmed now! Totally ready to join the Ubuntu flock!

Answer (score 0):

If windows is alone on its partition and all the important data are on other partitions, removing windows partition and installing Ubuntu on it will not affect the data on other partitions if you don't ask the installer wizard to use the entire disk or delete other partitions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am confirmed now! Totally ready to join the Ubuntu flock!

Comment: Nice! But if you never used Ubuntu, maybe you should install Ubuntu and let Windows working (at least in the beginning) with a dual boot if you have enough space on your HD. Ubuntu installer can do that for you too.